# Runtime Error: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmark.dat (Fail to execute script main)

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller, face-recognition, dlib

I've been trying to build executable file using pyinstaller. I have tested main.py file it works perfect but when I try in the exe file it shows an error.
Also I downloaded this shape_predictor_68_face_landmark.dat file and kept in the same folder as my main.py from this link https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models
I have tried solutions from the other stack questions that are similar, however, none of them worked for me

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\leena\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>

   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
   File "c:\users\leena\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "face_recognition\api.py", line 20, in <module>
 RuntimeError: Unable to open C:\Users\Leena\Desktop\hello world kivy\dist\main\face_recognition_models\models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
[1520] Failed to execute script main
```

my main.py contains:

import cv2

import face_recognition

import numpy as np

This is my main.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Leena\\Desktop\\hello world kivy'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\Leena\\Desktop\\hello world kivy\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been during a very similar thing where I was trying to build an executable file, using pyinstaller, for a face recognition project, and I got pretty much the exact  same error.

After spending hours trying to fix the error, I figured out a solution. As far as I understand, the library `face_recognition` (which I believe you must be using) contains its own shape predictor model files (including the one you are passing to the `data` parameter). These predictor model files are stored in `**/site-packages/face_recognition_models/models`. Now, the `site-packages` directory could be found in many places; you could be using a virtual environment (say, in Linux), in which case `site-packages` would be stored in `.venv/libs/python*/site-packages`, where `.venv` is the virtual environment directory that you are using. In a nutshell, you would have to find which `site-packages` directory your current Python is using.

For some reason (perhaps because they’re binary files), the aforementioned shape predictor models don’t get included along the `face_recognition` library when building the executable, and `face_recognition` needs them in order to function properly, even if you yourself provide your own shape predictor models.

You are on good track by passing your own shape predictor model as a file so it gets added to the executable. One problem here is that you are using the `datas` parameter, when `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` is a binary file. For this, you would pass the shape predictor model as an argument, the way you’re doing it, but to the `binaries` parameter instead. After doing this, you will need to do the following.

There could be a better fix than the one I’m about to provide, but once I realized all of this, in the `<script_name>.spec` file, I added the following arguments to the `binaries` parameter:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['<script_name>.py'],
             pathex=['<path_to_script_dir>'],  # this should automatically be filled
             binaries=[('$PARENT_DIR/site-packages/face_recognition_models/models/*',
                        'face_recognition_models/models'),
                       ('<path_to_parentdir_your_shape>/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat',
                        '<path_to_parentdir_your_shape>')],
             datas=[...],
             ...
```

what you would be doing here is manually adding those shape predictor models that `face_recognition` needs that don’t get added automatically during building. `$PARENT_DIR/site-packages/` would be the path to the `site-packages` directory that is currently being used (it depends on if you’re using virtual environments, your operative system, etc.). `path_to_parentdir_your_shape>` is basically the path to the directory where you have your shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat stored (it looks like your project directory is where you store your predictor file, so you would just replace those values in with the aforementioned `*.spec` file sample).

Now, how you provide the paths depends on the OS you’re using. I have been using Linux. In your case you would have to do what I just explained above, but providing valid Windows paths instead (using backslashes as path delimiters). Finally, in the `.../face_recognition_models/models/*` bit of the above code block, the * here means more or less “select everything in this directory“ (the `models` directory in our example). It might not work quite as such on Windows, in which case you could just manually pass multiple tuples to the `binaries` parameter, in a similar fashion as presented above, each containing the path to a specific predictor model in the `models` directory, until you have passed all the predictor models.

After this you should be able to build the executable from the `*.spec` file and it should give you no errors at runtime. It should work as you intend.