# Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat for face recognition

Tags: python, runtime-error, face-recognition, dlib

I have a project where I'll use the face_recognition library to recognise faces in Images. I tried the following code to make sure if the library is working:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np
import face_recognition

obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "C:\Users\علي\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "C:\Users\علي\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 20, in <module>
    pose_predictor_68_point = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_68_point_model)
RuntimeError: Unable to open C:\Users\علي\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\face_recognition_models\models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

I tried some sulotions that I found but nothing worked.

I downloaded dlib library in the proper way.

I redownloaded the file `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`.

I tried to copy the file to the directory of my python file, but still not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I downloaded dlib library in the proper way." (c) - Actually, dlib should not be downloaded but compiled too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime Error: Unable to open shape\_predictor\_68\_face\_landmark.dat (Fail to execute script main)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63981999/runtime-error-unable-to-open-shape-predictor-68-face-landmark-dat-fail-to-exec)